Override the maxRetries for only unauthorized error in RTK query
I have written base query like this and have added maxRetries count as 3.
export const baseQuery = retry(fetchBaseQuery({
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
    if (!headers.has('Accept-Language') && accessToken) {
      headers.set('Accept-Language', i18n.language || 'en');
    }
    return headers;
  },
}), { maxRetries: 3 });

I don't need to retry on unauthorized errors. When I get 401 status I need to stop retrying. How can I do that?
I thought to do this using a RTK middleware, but only middleware is triggered after all retries. So is there any way to stop retrying only when I get a HTTP status 401 error?

You can bail out of retries. Create a custom base query function that checks the fetchBaseQuery result status and preemptively fails the retry logic.
Example:
export const baseQuery = retry(
  async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    const result = await fetchBaseQuery({
      timeout: 5000,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
      prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
        if (!headers.has('Accept-Language') && accessToken) {
          headers.set('Accept-Language', i18n.language || 'en');
        }
        return headers;
      },
    })(args, api, extraOptions);

    if (result.error?.status === 401) {
      retry.fail(result.error);
    }

    return result;
  },
  { maxRetries: 3 },
);

